# Resize UICollectionViewCell on touch and hold

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to accomplish the same effect that the iPhone springboard does when moving icons. When the icons are in "wiggle" mode, and you touch and hold one, it will expand a little bit.

I am currently `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to handle the resize animation like this:

```
func handleLongPress(gestureReconizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    let p = gestureReconizer.location(in: collectionView)
    let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: p)

    if indexPath != nil && indexPath?.row != collectionData.count {
        if gestureReconizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {

            let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath!)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                cell?.frame = CGRect(x: (cell?.frame.origin.x)!, y: (cell?.frame.origin.y)!, width: (cell?.frame.width)! + 5, height: (cell?.frame.height)! + 5)
            })
        }
        else if gestureReconizer.state == .ended {

            let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath!)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                cell?.frame = CGRect(x: (cell?.frame.origin.x)!, y: (cell?.frame.origin.y)!, width: (cell?.frame.width)! - 5, height: (cell?.frame.height)! - 5)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This does resize the cell but as soon as I move it it goes back to its original size.